# How to break out of a loop in C

Tags: c, loops, break, bisection

I'm writing a bisection method algorithm to find the roots of polynomials. The second part of my code where it says if variable `FP` is equal to zero or absolute value of `b-a` it just breaks the if statement I guess.

I want the program to stop the for loop (iteration) entirely and return p. And at the end I want to print the number of iteration it took to get the solution but apparently using my printf statement it shows that the program keeps executing even thought the root (zero) is obtained.

Any ideas on how to stop the whole mechanism and return both the value of p which is zero and the exact number of iteration it took? Thanks

```
double computeroots(double a, double b, double epsilon, int MaxIter)
{
    double FA = pow(a,4) -4*a +  1;
    double FB = pow(b,4) - 4*b + 1;
    double FP;
    double p;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<MaxIter;i++) {
        if(FA * FB < 0) {
            p = a + (b-a)/2;
            FP = pow(p,4) - 4*p +1;
            if(FP == 0 || abs(b-a) < epsilon) {
                return p;
                break;
            } else if (FA * FP >0) {
                a =p;
                FA = FP;
            } else {
                b = p;
                FB = FP;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    printf("The number of iterations is: %d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: I didn't change your title, but it's definitely misleading. You only have one loop, not an outer and a nested loop.

Comment: You're incrementing `i` twice, so you only run half the iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Your `printf` statement isn't hit because you have a `return p;` before the `break` statement.  A `return` statement immediately exits the function.

You need to move the `return` statement to after the `printf`, or move the `printf` before the `return`:

```
        if(FP == 0 || abs(b-a) < epsilon)
        {
            printf("the number of iterations is : %d\n", i);
            return p;
        }
        ...

    printf("failed to converge after %d iterations\n", i);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Or, leave the break in place and move the `return` to the end of the function (where it belongs!)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `return` statement, then your `break` statement is useless. The return exits the scope of the function and goes back to the caller so no more instructions are executed afterward.

So this:

```
return p;
break;
```

should become:

```
printf("the number of iterations is : %d\n", i);
return p;
```

If you see that the exit condition is not correctly chosen I'd guess it's more a **finite precision problem**. You are checking `FP == 0` but `FP` is a `double` so you have to stop when `FP` is enough close to 0 not when it is exactly equal. Eg: `abs(FP) < epsilon`.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to return more than one value, you can do it with out-arguments. Change your function to

```
double computeroots(double a, double b, double epsilon, int MaxIter, int *numIterations)
```

call it like this:

```
int numIter;
soln = computeroots(a, b, epsilon, MaxIter, &numIter);
```

and in your function, just before returning, add:

```
*numIterations = i;
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian you saved the day.. But what I don't understand is that you're saying that computeroots should expect a pointer to integer named numIterations right!! so far so good, and when you call it you're using the ampersand which is also fine since it's a pointer.. But what's confusing is that you're declaring numIterations to be an integer and not a pointer to integer.. Which worked just fine but still I'm confused, we should declare it int *numIterations in main not just int numIterations

Comment: Also when I wanted to display the value of numIterations in printf, it returned a warning for incompatibility. I said printf(".....", *numIterations); which is wrong I know that there shouldn't be an asterisk but I don't understand why. Since it is a pointer it should get the asterisk before it in order to return the value it points to.. Without the asterisk, it should return the address of the variable it points to not the value... ANY EXPLANATIONS please

Comment: It's not a pointer. It's a normal integer buy you're passing it by reference to the function: & can be translated as "memory direction of ...". So inside the function you use * (which is the indirection operator and that you may find useful to translate as "content of the memory direction ...").
You can use the memory references of normal variables, they don't necessarly have to be pointers.

Comment: You need to pass the argument by reference (with the &) cause otherwise the function wouldn't be able to modify the value of a external variable (only local variables, declared inside de function or global variables).

Answer (score 1):

To merge all necessary modifications:

```
double computeroots(
  double a, 
  double b, 
  double epsilon, 
  size_t MaxIter, 
  size_t * pNumIter
) 
{
    double FA = pow(a,4) -4*a +  1;
    double FB = pow(b,4) - 4*b + 1;
    double FP;
    double p = NaN;
    size_t i;

    for(i=0; i<MaxIter; ++i) {
        if(FA * FB < 0) {
            p = a + (b-a)/2;
            FP = pow(p,4) - 4*p +1;
            if(FP == 0 || abs(b-a) < epsilon) {
                break;
            } else if (FA * FP >0) {
                a =p;
                FA = FP;
            } else {
                b = p;
                FB = FP;
            }
        }
    }

    *pNumIter = i;

    printf("the number of iterations is : %z\n", *pNumIter);

    return p;
}
```

Call it like so:

```
double a, b, epsilon;
size_t sizeMax, sizeIterations;

... /* some initialisations here */

double d = computeroots(a, b, epsilon, sizeMax, &sizeIterations);
```

Notes on modifications:

- removed misplaced `return`
- added missing return at the end
- changed `int`s to be `size_t`, as an `unsigned` type suits better for counters
- added reference to additional `size_t` variable to return number of iterations
- removed second incrementation of `i`

Comment: What is *"mods/s"*? *"modifications"*?

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array of doubles, where the first element is the result, and the second one is the number of iteration.

Or, you pass the reference to a variable to the function, and assign to it, like this:

```
double compute_something(int param1, int param2, int* iterations) {
    // your code ...
    // when you want to return, use this:
    *iterations = 5;
    return 1.23;
    // your code ...
}

int iter;
double result = compute_something(1,2, &iter);
```

After this, result contains the result, and iter the number of iterations that you stored.
This solution would likely be better, because you are not returning the number of iterations (which is clearly an integer number) as a double.